# Primefaces selectOneMenu focus not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using `PrimeFaces 5.1` in my application,I used `selectOneMenu` inside of `dataTable`, When I press on add more button to need to focus `selectOneMenu` button.

**Sample Code**

**JavaScript**

```
function focusMenu(id)
{
var focusId="#{p:component('mainTable')}"+":"+id;
PrimeFaces.focus(final);
}
```

**xhtml**

```
<div style="padding-left:4px;height: 
expression(this.scrollHeight > 399? '400px' : 'auto');max-height:400px;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:auto;">  
<p:dataTable id="mainTable" value=#{main.UserDataTable} .....>
<p:column headerText="Drop Down">
<p:selectOneMenu id="dropdDownId"...>
.....
</p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Operation">
<p:commandButton value="Add More Row" action="{user.addMoreRowAction}"
update="mainTable"/>
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</div>
```

**Java**

```
public String addMoreRowAction()
{
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("focusMenu('"+ rowIndex + ":dropdDownId"')");
return null;
}
```

Here the above code is work fine to focus the last added `selectOneMenu` as what I expected, but the browser scroll bar is not move down based on focusing the recently added `selectOneMenu` component.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the scrollbar to the focus id using `scrollTop` function.
Pass the `focusid` into the function.

```
function setScrollPos(focusId){
    $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: $(focusId).offset().top-65
    }, 1000);
}
```

Call the above function

```
function focusMenu(id)
{
var focusId="#{p:component('mainTable')}"+":"+id;
PrimeFaces.focus(final);
setScrollPos(focusId); <<------
}
```